# WordPress доступ к функциям

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Здравствуйте! 
Есть file.php  лежащий в каталоге темы, как сделать так что бы он имел доступ к стандартны функциям php например the_title(); и т.п.

get_template_part(file.php) работает не так как нужно, он выводит содержимое там где выводить не нужно.

В file.php небольшой скрипт, если коротко он формирует некий специфический вывод, записей в зависимости от переданного в него id записи через jqery а после результат передается назад в формате html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что выхотите сделать - неправильно с точки зрения архитектуры *Wordpress*. Не стОит создавать файлы, которые запускаются отдельно от *Wordpress*.

Если вы хотите что-то выполнить через *AJAX*-запрос в *Wordpress* напишите плагин. В нем зарегистрируйте ваш обработчик действия `wp_ajax_nopriv`. Внутри этого обработчика у вас будет доступ к API *Wordpress*

Получится что-то вроде такого:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfunc', 'my_functionality_handler');

function my_functionality_handler() {
    // Тут выполняете ваши задумки и возвращаете результат
}
```

Чтобы обработчик был вызван, нужно отправить GET или POST запрос на `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`. Для рассмотренного примера в запросе должна быть переменная `action` с значением `myfunc` (у вас значение может быть другим).

Дополнительная информация:

- [Использование AJAX в плагинах](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) (на английском языке)
- Описание [wp_ajax_(action)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29) (на английском языке)
- Описание [wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_%28action%29) (на английском языке)
- [Статья](http://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html#ajax-vo-vneshnej-chasti-wordpress) про использование AJAX в Wordpress (на русском языке)

**Дополнено**

Кстати, действительно можно разместить обработчик AJAX действия в файле `functions.php` в директории вашей темы.

Comment: Спасибо большое за комментарий.

Подскажите как адаптировать мою функцию js для выозва плагина который как я понимаю будет  в function.php 
код
$("button[data-shouldrequest]").on('click',function(){
        $.post("cart.php", { order: $(this).data("unique-id")})
                .done(function(data) {
                    $('#cart').html(data);
                });
    });

Как кстати добавить файл я разобрался это делает функция require_once , я очень поверхностно знаком с js, а хочется сделать правильно, потому буду рад вашей подсказке, или ссылке с примером и описанием. Еще раз спасибо)

Comment: @Alex Добавьте во второй параметр вызова `$.post` параметр `action: 'myfunc'` и вместо `cart.php` напишите `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`

Comment: Спасибо огромное, за верное решение!)

Comment: То, что написал Тутанхамон, без всякого сомнения - классический подход. Замечу, однако, что есть некоторый минус. Дело в том, что при таком подходе, при каждом обращении через ajax подгружается вся система Вордпресс (включая все плагины). Это значительно увеличивает время обработки. Если быстрое взаимодействие  со скриптом критично, мне кажется стоит вынести его в отдельный файл который будет погружать только нужные части ВП. Хотелось бы узнать, что Вы (tutankhamun) думаете об этом.

Comment: @s976 Для облегченного доступа к WP есть константа `SHORTINIT`. Можно пользоваться, как написано в [статье](http://wp-kama.ru/id_3014/podgruzhaem-sredu-wordpress-s-minimalnoy-nagruzkoy-konstanta-shortinit.html). Однако, при этом нужно будет понимать что большинство "родных" функций тоже не будут работать, придется тащить из исходников или писать свои велосипеды.

Comment: Ну да. Но можно подключить отдельно нужные части. Например, `require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/post.php' )`

Comment: @s976 Согласен. Все равно нужно понимать что делаешь. Некоторые такие "части" могут тянуть за собой другие.

Comment: Спасибо за столь развернутые ответы!)