# AJAX запрос со страницы на странцу, как получить ответ?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Отправляю AJAX запрос со страницы на ту же страницу, в RESPONSE мы получем полнностью весь исходный код страницы, а мне нужно получить только результаты выполнения PHP кода на этой странице, как это сделать?

Comment: Не очень понятно, что именно вы понимаете под "исходным кодом страницы"? Вы хотите получить данные не в формате HTML-страницы? Если так, то добавьте параметр GET-запроса или HTTP-заголовок, по которому скрипт сможет отпределить что это AJAX-запрос

Comment: В общем запрос к wordpress странике, в коде шаблона имеется обработчик с функциями Wordpress (что делает очень сложным вынос обработчика в сторнний файл в другое место), я передаю запрос со страницы на страницу, шаблон показывает сначала HTML код всей старницы, а вместе с ним - выполнение кода обработчика происходит и вывод данных на экран вместе с страницей.

Comment: Вынос обработчика из под крыла WP не нужен. Вам сюда http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468272/177613

Comment: Кстати, заметьте, ваш вопрос очень не похож на ваш комментарий. Как будто два разных вопроса. Старайтесь формулировать вопросы более полно.